# Adding value list (domain) to an ArcGIS Online feature layer with Public account

Tags: arcgis-online, domains, value-list

I need to add an item list (fish species e.g.) to an ArcGIS Online feature layer. I have a Public account, am the owner of the layer and have tried to follow the documentation: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/define-attribute-lists-and-ranges.htm However, the layers item page has no **Data** tab only the **Overview** and **Settings** tabs are available. As the owner I would have expected to see all tabs.

Is this a limitation on AGOL public accounts and, if so, is there another way to add the desired list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it appears that this is a limitation of the public account. The documentation you followed applies to Hosted Feature Layers.

The Prerequisites for publishing Hosted Feature Layers are documented in the [publishing documentation](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/hosted-web-layers.htm). One of the prereqs is the publisher's account is part of an organization.

Comment: I did not test this by publishing from 2 different accounts to see the difference, maybe you can?

Comment: Thanks, I no longer have access to an organizational account so I may need to see if there is a subscription that meets my needs.